# 4Store vs Sesame, features

Tags: jakarta-ee, rdf, sesame, triplestore, 4store

I'm looking for a triple store to use with Java EE.

I ended with 2 possibilities, 4Store and Sesame but can't see the real difference between the two in term of features.
I don't mind about performances details.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as this kind of "opinion-based" question is considered off-topic for this site. I recommend that you try and determine what your requirements are, then find out how each tool meets those requirements, and then pick one. If you have more specific questions about either tool, you might also try answers.semanticweb.com.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I'm asking what are the differences in term of features, I don't think this is "opinion-based", that's facts.

Comment: I don't dispute that, but any answer you get is likely to be opinion-based in the sense that it will highlight a particular feature of one tool. Without knowing more about your use case requirements it's not really possible to make a valid objective recommendation.

Having said that, I gave it a stab, hope it's useful, I've tried to be as objective as possible.

Comment: My use case is quite simple : import RDF, store in a triple store, setup a SPARQL end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a full list of features for either tool, but I reckon that an important difference for your use case (given what little you've told us) is that wile 4Store is an RDF database implementation (or "triplestore"), Sesame is a framework API for handling RDF in Java, giving access to multiple triplestore implementations (including some of its own, but also many third-party products). The possible advantage of this is that it allows you switching to a different database (if you so require) without major changes to your code.

I would also imagine that Sesame's API, being developed in and for Java, is slightly more feature-rich and easy to use in a Java EE environment, but this is merely an assumption as I am not sufficiently familiar with 4Store to make an actual comparison.

(disclosure: I am on the Sesame development team)

Comment: Thanks, I see the main difference between the two system and can guess that for a simple use case there isn't big differences.